# Joomla 1.6 Custom SEF router.php - my component cannot read url variables

Tags: joomla, joomla-sef-urls

Hi I have a bit of a problem. I have written a custom component for Joomla 1.6 and I have also just written a custom router.php file for my component so I can have 'pretty' SEF urls.

E.g. from

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_my_component&view=list&id=1:test
```

TO

```
http://www.domain.com/com_my_component/list/1-test
```

Very nice, yes! But the problem I am now having is that when I use this piece of code to get a url variable:

```
$id = JRequest::getVar('id', 'blank');
```

And print it out, I get:

```
blank
```

when I should get the id value. It seems that having now set the SEF urls that my component cannot retrieve the ids and such that actually drive a database driven website. Please could someone give me some insight as to what I might be doing wrong.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in my "ParseRoute" function in my router.php I was not checking and settings the correct url segments. This function is used to check the segments and then set the correct variable with the right segment value depending on the location of it in the url.